# Unable to update UI setting Request failed with status code: 403 Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am trying to change discover:sampleSize 500 to 1000 but I am getting an error Unable to update UI setting with superuser.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60426689/edit) to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://$SITEURL$/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This answer might help you:
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/unable-to-update-ui-setting-request-failed-with-status-code-403/201409

Your user role might be missing access to the ".kibana" index.